# How are these ObjC declarations different: ie what is this really doing?

Tags: objective-c, declaration

I'm trying to understand what this is doing in each case. Can someone explain what the first case is doing in detail and how it differs from the second? Thanks // :)

```
//declare in first case
NSManagedObjectModel *mom();

NSManagedObjectModel *mom() {
 static NSManagedObjectModel *mom = nil;
//implementation goes here...
 return mom;
}
```

vs.

```
//no declaration in second case
- (NSManagedObjectModel *) mom {
 static NSManagedObjectModel *mom = nil;
//implementation goes here...
 return mom;
}
```

Comment: Well, the first code sample isn't valid, for starters. Also, one appears to be a function and the other a method, so the difference is not "no declaration." Methods can be declared just like functions can.

Comment: @Chuck sure it is; it's a C function called `mom` that returns an `NSManagedObjectModel*`.

Comment: Was it OK to implement a C-function without parentheses???

Comment: @Dave DeLong: You're telling me that `NSManagedObjectModel *mom {` is the beginning of a valid function definition?

Comment: It didn't compile on my GCC. Maybe it was allowed pre-ANSI? I'm not sure...

Comment: @Chuck fair enough, you need the `()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the first case is meant to be a C function declaration and definition, and the parentheses in the definition have been accidentally omitted.  So I'm putting them in.

Comment: err, I think the second example is supposed to be a class method... or at least should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is a standalone function; it's not tied to a class. You'd call it like:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *retVal = mom();
```

The second is an instance method definition, and thus is defined in the context of a class. You'd call it like:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *retVal = [someObject mom];
```